Azure Service Bus SQL Filter not working based on the condition
I am trying to filter the messages based on Client Id under the subscription by using SQL Filter in Azure Service Bus Topic. Even after applying the SQL filter, we are still getting other Client Id related messages under the subscription. Could you please help us to resolve this issue?


Please edit your question and include the message body and the properties. If you’re trying to filter on something inside message body, then it won’t work.

When posting a question, it's not enough to say there's a problem. You need to provide the details to allow reproduction of the problem, or sufficient details to identify what's happening.

Make sure you are adding the SqlFilter properly like below with correct payload message:-
I have created one subscription and added the Filter below:-
Message Body payload:-
{
  "orderId": "124",
  "color": "blue",
  "ClientId": "c0c952e9-5254-45b5-b838-6d26a31435cb",
  "priority": "medium"
}

color='blue' AND ClientId='c0c952e9-5254-45b5-b838-6d26a31435cb'

Output:-

C# code to perform the operation:-
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class SendMessages
{
    static string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://silicon9.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxxxxx89vA+ASbB60thA=";
    static string topicName = "valleytopic";

    public static async Task Main()
    {
        await using var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
        ServiceBusSender sender = client.CreateSender(topicName);

        
        var message1 = new ServiceBusMessage(new BinaryData(@"{
            ""orderId"": ""123"",
            ""color"": ""blue"",
            ""quantity"": 5,
            ""priority"": ""low""
        }"));

        
        var message2 = new ServiceBusMessage(new BinaryData(@"{
            ""orderId"": ""124"",
            ""priority"": ""medium""
        }"));
        message2.ApplicationProperties["color"] = "blue";
        message2.ApplicationProperties["ClientId"] = "c0c952e9-5254-45b5-b838-6d26a31435cb";

       
        var message3 = new ServiceBusMessage(new BinaryData(@"{
            ""orderId"": ""125"",
            ""priority"": ""high""
        }"));
        message3.ApplicationProperties["user.color"] = "red";
        message3.ApplicationProperties["quantity"] = 20;

        
        var message4 = new ServiceBusMessage(new BinaryData(@"{
            ""orderId"": ""126"",
            ""color"": ""red"",
            ""quantity"": 15
        }"));
        message4.Subject = "red";
        message4.CorrelationId = "high";

        await sender.SendMessageAsync(message1);
        await sender.SendMessageAsync(message2);
        await sender.SendMessageAsync(message3);
        await sender.SendMessageAsync(message4);

        Console.WriteLine("Messages sent.");
    }
}

Output:-

When I peeked message:-

